# Eclipse window relocation on Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos, macos-sierra

I've just updated my MacBook to macOS Sierra. I've got this weird problem with Eclipse where every time I try to open anything with autocomplete (Cmd+Mouse Hover) or even if I just hover over an element that has attached Javadoc, the console window which I keep on my second monitor, snaps over to my primary monitor and covers whatever it is that I've hovered over.

Before Hover:
[image: Screenshot 1]

After Hover:
[image: Screenshot 2]

For reference I hovered over `list.add` on line 23.

Does anyone know why the Sierra update causes this behaviour? I can dock the console window inside Eclipse and it doesn't do it but it's a right pain because it makes my code editing window smaller. Normally I have the package explorer and Ant tabs open as well so docking the console makes my code window positively minuscule.

Any fixes or even reproductions would be heartening, just so I know I'm not going completely mad.

Update: It's not just the console, any window that's not attached to the main Eclipse window will exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Same problem here... Have not found a fix yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Mission Control System Preferences]

Uncheck last check box (Displays have separate Spaces), it has other drawbacks but it fixes 2 windows eclipse on multiple monitors.

EDIT : Still works on High Sierra

Comment: That's champion that is

Comment: And what is the champion answer for setups WITH different spaces? o_O